# fork a process with multiple thread C

Tags: c, pthreads, fork

I'm following this guide about `pthread` and `fork` but I'm confused about how the following code works.
The following code is from https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Pthreads%2C-Part-2%3A-Usage-in-Practice

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static pid_t child = -2;

void *sleepnprint(void *arg) {
 printf("%d:%s starting up...\n", getpid(), (char *) arg);

 while (child == -2) {sleep(1);} /* Later we will use condition variables */

 printf("%d:%s finishing...\n",getpid(), (char*)arg);

 return NULL;  
}
int main() {
 pthread_t tid1, tid2;
 pthread_create(&tid1,NULL, sleepnprint, "New Thread One");
 pthread_create(&tid2,NULL, sleepnprint, "New Thread Two");
 
 child = fork();
 printf("%d:%s\n",getpid(), "fork()ing complete");
 sleep(3);
   
 printf("%d:%s\n",getpid(), "Main thread finished");
 
 pthread_exit(NULL);
 return 0; /* Never executes */
}
```

```
8970:New Thread One starting up...
8970:fork()ing complete
8973:fork()ing complete
8970:New Thread Two starting up...
8970:New Thread Two finishing...
8970:New Thread One finishing...
8970:Main thread finished
8973:Main thread finished
```

1. Is the 8970 the parent process?
2. From the website, it says the child only had single thread, so does it mean the child process doesn't go to `sleepnprint` function?
3. Why do the `8970:fork()ing complete` `8973:fork()ing complete` print before `8970:New Thread Two starting up...`? Are the order of thread and process random?

Comment: You cannot modify a variable (child) in one thread and look at it in another thread without proper synchronisation.

Comment: Why even use fork() if threading is available? It's a dysfunctional function from an era before multi-threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread (main() function) creates two threads with [pthread_create()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) but as they are threads, they are part of the same process (getpid() returns 8970 for the main thread and the secondary threads). If you want the task identifiers, call [gettid()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid) in the thread entry point (you will respectively get 8971 and 8972).

Then, the father forks and both the father and child processes continue in the main() function. They respectively display their pid: 8970 and 8973.

When a multi-threaded process forks, only the calling thread is "reproduced" in the child process (the other threads of the father process are not forked: the child process is mono-threaded until it creates new threads on its side). So, in your example, the child process number 8973 does not have the two threads created in the father process (number 8970).

Yes all the threads and processes run in parallel (in any order).

To illustrate the preceding, here is a slight enhanced version of your program:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE  // To get gettid()
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static volatile pid_t child = -2;

void *sleepnprint(void *arg)
{
  printf("Process %d, Task %d:%s starting up...\n", getpid(), gettid(), (char *) arg);

  // This is not the best way to synchronize threads but this works here:
  // once the main thread returns from fork(), child = pid of child process
  // (i.e. != -2)
  while (child == -2) {sleep(1);} /* Later we will use condition variables */

  printf("Process %d, Task %d:%s finishing...\n", getpid(), gettid(), (char*)arg);

  return NULL;  
}

int main() {

  pthread_t tid1, tid2;
  pthread_create(&tid1,NULL, sleepnprint, "New Thread One");
  pthread_create(&tid2,NULL, sleepnprint, "New Thread Two");
 
  child = fork();

  // In father process: child = child process pid
  // In child process: child = 0

  if (child == 0) {

    // This is the child process

    printf("%d:%s\n",getpid(), "Child process finished");

    exit(0);
  }

  // Father process

  printf("%d:%s\n",getpid(), "fork()ing complete");
  sleep(3);

  printf("%d:%s\n",getpid(), "Main thread finished");

  pthread_exit(NULL);
  return 0; /* Never executes */
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
$ gcc example.c -l pthread
$ ./a.out
Process 6141, Task 6142:New Thread One starting up...
Process 6141, Task 6142:New Thread One finishing...
Process 6141, Task 6143:New Thread Two starting up...
Process 6141, Task 6143:New Thread Two finishing...
6144:Child process finished
6141:fork()ing complete
6141:Main thread finished
```